# LValue required - Reason and solution for my first program

Tags: c

I am doing my 1st year engineering.
I am beginner to programming.
I have program where I get the error - **LValue required** on the lines - 30,31 and 32 (marked in the code below).

What is the reason for the error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct employee
{
      char empname[30];
      int leave;
};
main()
{
    struct employee a[1000];
    int bp=5000,salary,x,i,j,k;
    char w[30];
    int t;
    x=(bp*120)/100;
    salary=bp+x;
    printf("Enter the number of employees:");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter employee name and number of days he/she took leave:");
        scanf("%s%d",&a[i].empname, &a[i].leave);
    }

    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        for(k=i+1;k<j;k++)
        {
            if(a[i].empname[0]>a[k].empname[0])
            {
                w= a[i].empname;            // Line 30
                a[i].empname=a[k].empname;  // Line 31
                a[k].empname=w;             // Line 32
                t=a[i].leave;
                a[i].leave=a[k].leave;
                a[k].leave=t;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<j;j++)
    {
        if(a[i].leave>10)
        salary=salary-((a[i].leave-10)*366);
    }
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        printf("Employee name = %s\nNumber of days leave = %d\nSalary = %d\n",a[i].empname,a[i].leave,salary);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: SO is not a free debugger service, learn to use the debugger tools available to you instead, step through the code, and check what type is being assigned to what var

Comment: off-topic: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing a code, questions about codereview should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to make string copy for permutation in these lines

```
w= a[i].empname;
a[i].empname=a[k].empname;
a[k].empname=w;
```

you can not make string copy in this way in C

you have to use [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) instead

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

so you can make the permutation in this way

```
strcpy(w, a[i].empname);
strcpy(a[i].empname, a[k].empname);
strcpy(a[k].empname, w);
```

Comment: strcpy() worked. The new issue is the program terminates abruptly by executing only the first for() loop.

Answer (score 1):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and its value will be the address of the first element in the array.  This converted expression is not an *lvalue*, meaning it may not be the target of an assignment.

If you want to copy the contents of one array to another, you'll need to use a library function.  For C strings (arrays of `char` with a terminating 0 value) use `strcpy` or `strncpy`.  For other array types, use `memcpy`.

So, those lines should be

```
strcpy( w, a[i].empname );
strcpy( a[i].empname, a[k].empname );
strcpy( a[k].empname, a[i].empname );
```